# Ajax: 403 Custom message in the console instead of error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I have a nodejs app where I am using ajax to load a particular data from s3. Sometimes the data will not be available for certain clients. In that case I want to show custom message in the console instead of an error. I used `try catch` with no luck.

This is my code:

```
try {
 ajax(url, function(res){
      //use the data to do things
    }, undefined, {});
}
catch (e) {
 console.log('Data not loaded: ' + e)
}
```

This is the error message that I want to replace with a custom message:

> GET https://somelink.json 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: You're doing AJAX exception handling wrong. You need to grab the error from the `error` callback. You're treating an asynchronous piece of code as synchronous with your `try..catch`, which is good exception handling only for *synchronous* code or asynchronous code using `async/await`

Comment: can you show me where exactly I have to make the change?

Comment: see @jkordas answer below..

Comment: Isn't this node, i.e. server side? Why would you use jQuery for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use jquery.ajax function. It will look something like this.

```
$.ajax(
  {url: url}
).done(function(res){
  //use the data to do things
}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  console.log('Data not loaded: ' + textStatus)
});
```